# Azure AD exchange access_token with id_token v.1.0 endpoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, openid-connect

I will draw a scenario, and need some suggestions:

I'm using Azure AD (v1.0 endpoint), a single-page app (SPA) and a web API. The SPA establishes the user's identity using OpenID Connect, authenticates the user and receives an `id_token` and `access_token` for the back-end web API.

Now, we don't want the SPA to do access control decision based on the `id_token` received within the SPA app.

Instead, the SPA sends the `access_token` to the back-end web API to access it, and now we want back-end web API to make an access control decision based on the `roles` claim found in the `id_token`, but which the back-end does not receive from the SPA.

The question is, is it possible for the back-end web API to send received `access_token` to Azure AD token endpoint and receive the relevant `id_token` for the user so that the back-end web API receives an `id_token` containing the `roles` claims for the user, in order to make an access control decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues with the approach as you describe it:

1. The app roles would be defined on the native client application (the SPA). Though you can technically define app roles in the manifest, you'll notice the Azure portal won't let you assign users or groups to a native client app. (Which sort of makes sense, because, as you've rightly said, you don't want to do any access control in the native client app.)
2. You can't do what you've described (exchange an `access_token` intended for one audience, for an `id_token` intended for a different audience). There are some variants of token exchange which you *can* do, but none of them would help you in this situation.

Instead, what you should do is define the app roles *on the web API*. Then, assign the users to the corresponding app role for the web API. When these users sign in to the SPA, and the SPA gets an access token on their behalf to the web API, you'll notice the access token will contain the `roles` claim, populated with the appropriate values.

Summarizing:

1. Under App registrations for the web API, define your  `appRoles` in the app manifest (or on the Application object directly, using (for example) Azure AD PowerShell).
2. Under Enterprise apps for the web API, assign users and/or groups to their corresponding app roles, and choose whether or not app role assignment is required or not*. (Or do so directly on the ServicePrincipal object.)
3. Under App registrations for the SPA (the Application object), add the web API as a required permission.

*If you choose to require app role assignment for the web API (under Enterprise apps > Properties), the SPA will not be able to get an access token for users who are not assigned to an app role for the web API. If you choose *not* to require app role assignment , users who are not assigned an app role will be able to sign in to SPA and the SPA *will* be able to get an access token on their behalf for the web API, but the access token will *not* contain a `roles` claim.