# With Azure AD 'User Assignment Required' turned on, how to handle unauthorized users in same tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an app registration for which users can log into a SPA app using the [MSAL library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). This works fine until a user already is logged in with an account in the same tenant as the app, but not authorised by being assigned to a role. They are redirected to an azure login error page stating:

`AADSTS50105: The signed in user '{user name}' is not assigned to a role for the application '{uid}'({App reg name}).`

I can't see any way to prevent this. **How can I catch this failure in  my apps MSAL library and allow the user to sign in with a different account?**

You can also find my issue posted to an MSAL github issue here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/3949

Comment: similar threads  :   [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285963/azure-ad-authentication-redirect-access-denied-to-static-page-net-core-vue/68649938#68649938)>(Changing the ‘User assignment required’ to No, grant admin consent and then set  user assignment to yes.)  , [AADSTS50105](https://wiki.resolution.de/doc/saml-sso/latest/all/knowledgebase-articles/technical/the-signed-in-user-is-not-assigned-to-a-role-for-the-application) , [thread3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201430/azure-ad-exchange-access-token-with-id-token-v-1-0-endpoint/49202627#49202627)

Comment: thanks. Turning off 'user assignment required' i believe should not be the fix as i want to exclude users in the same tenant from gaining access and also enforce adding users via the user groups